# 28 extra bytes in bss

Tags: c, memory-management

```
struct abc
{
   char cc[32];
} mystruct;

int  main()
{
}
```

When I run the above program, the .bss section has 64 bytes. I was expecting it to be 36 bytes . 32 bytes for mystruct and 4 bytes which is taken by other libraries.

If I change `char cc[32]` to `char cc[31]` then I get 36 bytes in .bss.

```
-bash-3.00$ g++ bssSize.cc

-bash-3.00$ readelf --sections ./a.out | grep bss
  [23] .bss              NOBITS          08049580 000578 000040 00  WA  0   0 32
-bash-3.00$
```

64 is 000040 in hex

Why are these extra 28 bytes there in .bss ?

Comment: there is a more than just your code in `.bss`. You sure there is nothing else in there?

Comment: Perhaps `.bss` is only extended in 32-byte chunks or something. You might need to investigate the ELF spec to find out...

Comment: Am I the only one following along who's still wondering how we got to 36 bytes when the OP changes the array size to 31? (Given that 36 is very clearly not a multiple of 32)

Answer (score 4):

The last column of the `readelf` output is alignment, and the value shown is indeed "32". So, the BSS size is being rounded up to the nearest multiple of 32 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

objdump -sSx a.out yields, among other things...

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000400238  0000000000400238  00000238  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  0000000000400254  0000000000400254  00000254  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000400274  0000000000400274  00000274  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .gnu.hash     0000001c  0000000000400298  0000000000400298  00000298  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .dynsym       00000048  00000000004002b8  00000000004002b8  000002b8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .dynstr       00000038  0000000000400300  0000000000400300  00000300  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .gnu.version  00000006  0000000000400338  0000000000400338  00000338  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .gnu.version_r 00000020  0000000000400340  0000000000400340  00000340  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .rela.dyn     00000018  0000000000400360  0000000000400360  00000360  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  9 .rela.plt     00000018  0000000000400378  0000000000400378  00000378  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 10 .init         00000018  0000000000400390  0000000000400390  00000390  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 11 .plt          00000020  00000000004003b0  00000000004003b0  000003b0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 12 .text         000001c8  00000000004003d0  00000000004003d0  000003d0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 13 .fini         0000000e  0000000000400598  0000000000400598  00000598  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 14 .rodata       00000004  00000000004005a8  00000000004005a8  000005a8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 15 .eh_frame_hdr 0000002c  00000000004005ac  00000000004005ac  000005ac  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 16 .eh_frame     000000a4  00000000004005d8  00000000004005d8  000005d8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 17 .ctors        00000010  0000000000600e28  0000000000600e28  00000e28  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 18 .dtors        00000010  0000000000600e38  0000000000600e38  00000e38  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 19 .jcr          00000008  0000000000600e48  0000000000600e48  00000e48  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 20 .dynamic      00000190  0000000000600e50  0000000000600e50  00000e50  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 21 .got          00000008  0000000000600fe0  0000000000600fe0  00000fe0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 22 .got.plt      00000020  0000000000600fe8  0000000000600fe8  00000fe8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 23 .data         00000010  0000000000601008  0000000000601008  00001008  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 24 .bss          00000040  0000000000601020  0000000000601020  00001018  2**5
                  ALLOC
 25 .comment      0000002a  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001018  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

item 24, under "Algn" we see 2**5 or 2^5 aka 32. This indicates bss is allocated in 32 byte chunks because it is 32 bit aligned.

Comment: thanks.... If it is 32 byte aligned then why do i see the output of below code as 36     -bash-3.00$ cat  bssSize.cc
struct abc
{
   char cc[31];
} mystruct;

int  main()
{
}
-bash-3.00$ g++ bssSize.cc
-bash-3.00$ size --format=sysv ./a.out | grep bss
.bss               36   134518136
-bash-3.00$

Answer (score 0):

objdump -t a.out |grep bss gives you

```
    08049660 l    d  .bss   00000000              .bss
    08049660 l     O .bss   00000001              completed.5745
    08049660 g       *ABS*  00000000              __bss_start
    08049680 g     O .bss   00000020              mystruct
```

the expected (00000020 in hex) of size 32 bytes.