# Size of bss increments by unexpected bytes in case of static array

Tags: c, memory

Consider the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int arr[20] = {0};
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above program using gcc on a 32-bit linux machine. I then ran the size command on the executable. The results I got were as follows:

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1033        276     112    1421     58d ./a.out
```

The results without any variable in the program was:

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1033        276       4    1313     521 ./a.out
```

So, my question is: why is there an increment of 108 bytes instead of 80 bytes.
I read in some answers on this website that this is due to the requirement for bss to be aligned to 32 bits, but 84 (4 - earlier + 80 (due to array)) is already 32 bit aligned.

**EDIT :**

I tried running the following command:

```
objdump -sSx a.out | grep bss
```

and the output I got was:

```
 24 .bss          00000070  0804a020  0804a020  0000101c  2**5
0804a020 l    d  .bss   00000000              .bss
0804a020 l     O .bss   00000001              completed.6590
0804a040 l     O .bss   00000050              arr.1825
0804a090 g       .bss   00000000              _end
0804a01c g       .bss   00000000              __bss_start
```

The value 2**5 in the first line denotes alignment to 32 bits as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152865/2407962

But, I don't really know what to make of the output. Please help!

Comment: There's 1 byte to keep track of initialization (completed), 31 bytes for alignment, 80 bytes for the array.  1 + 31 + 80 = 112

Comment: @HansPassant: Can you please explain, what is the completed bit for and why is it not present in case of if only a single int variable is present in BSS?

Comment: The array gets initialized only once, the first time the function runs.  Thus the "completed" variable.  Just look at the generated machine code, you'll see it testing that variable.

Comment: @HansPassant why 32 byte alignment, that seems like a lot.

Comment: @Matt - AVX doesn't come for free.  Bytes are cheap however, those 31 cost a quarter of a billionth penny today.

Answer (score 0):

You can answer that question yourself with these two methods:

1. Generate memory dump from your executable file:

`objdump -x --syms executable-file > output-file.dmp`

2. Generate map file during the linking step:

`gcc ... -Wl,-Map=map-file.map ...`

In both of these files you can find all the info about contents of sections, alignment, placement etc.

Comment: Yes, I already did that, but I don't really get the reason for an increment of 108 bytes in .bss. Please direct what all fields are important in the output of above commands concerning my question.

Comment: @TapanAnand - by searching for string ".bss" in the .dmp file you find it in lines that describe objects placed in that section. First hex number is the address, second hex number is the size, last string is the name of symbol (usually the name of variable/constant/function/..., but may be mangled). You can also use text compare (like diff) to compare .dmp file with and without your change.